# Multiple nested If statement - And Or not working

Tags: excel, if-statement

Using a nested If Statement in Excel I have been trying to obtain results using the following criteria:

**within 100 and 75000 Volts but should accept 11; 22; 25; 26; 30; 33; 66 
as they will be in kV**

Source data is in a table `Transformers` and the formula is also returning data on two other tables `MASTER` and `META`.

I have tried in vain all kinds of `IF/AND/OR` variants of the following, however I have rarely used nested if statements before so am not at home with the logic.  Any help gratefully received !
Thank you

`=IF(MASTER!N2="Failed Check 1","Failed Check 1",IF(META!N2="Failed Check 2","Failed Check 2"), IF(OR(Transformers!T2>=110, Transformers!T2<=75000) OR(Transformers!T2=11, Transformers!T2=22, Transformers!T2=25, Transformers!T2=26, Transformers!T2=30, Transformers!T2=33, Transformers!T2=66),"Failed Check 3","Passed Check 3"))`

Thank you

Comment: I wouldn't multiply those OR statements to cut down on how confusing this is. Just put them all into one OR `=IF(MASTER!N2="Failed Check 1","Failed Check 1",IF(META!N2="Failed Check 2","Failed Check 2"), IF(OR(Transformers!T2>=110, Transformers!T2<=75000, Transformers!T2=11, Transformers!T2=22, Transformers!T2=25, Transformers!T2=26, Transformers!T2=30, Transformers!T2=33, Transformers!T2=66),"Failed Check 3","Passed Check 3"))`

Comment: Thank you John, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need an AND as the first term in your OR. The parenthesis also looked incorrect. Once the complexity reaches a certain stage it sometimes helps to compose the formulas in something like Notepad with white-space to display the logic:

```
=IF(MASTER!N2="Failed Check 1",
    "Failed Check 1",
     IF(META!N2="Failed Check 2",
         "Failed Check 2", 
          IF(OR(
                AND(Transformers!T2>=110, Transformers!T2<=75000),
                Transformers!T2=11, 
                Transformers!T2=22, 
                Transformers!T2=25, 
                Transformers!T2=26, 
                Transformers!T2=30, 
                Transformers!T2=33, 
                Transformers!T2=66
                ),
             "Failed Check 3",
             "Passed Check 3"
           )
       )
    )
```

Without linebreaks this is:

```
=IF(MASTER!N2="Failed Check 1","Failed Check 1",IF(META!N2="Failed Check 2","Failed Check 2", IF(OR(AND(Transformers!T2>=110, Transformers!T2<=75000),Transformers!T2=11, Transformers!T2=22, Transformers!T2=25, Transformers!T2=26, Transformers!T2=30, Transformers!T2=33, Transformers!T2=66),"Failed Check 3","Passed Check 3")))
```

Comment: Thank you John this has been extremely helpful.  Solved !

Answer (score 0):

Based on your conditions, I would recommend you implement this one liner which assumes your data is in cell A1.

```
=IF(OR(AND(A1>=100,A1<=75000),A1=11,A1=22,A1=25,A1=26,A1=30,A1=33,A1=66),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Although this only returns TRUE or FALSE, which doesn't tell you which check it has passed.

Comment: Thank you, I had already applied a sollution offered above, much appreciated though.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(MASTER!N2="Failed Check 1","Failed Check 1",IF(META!N2="Failed Check 2","Failed Check 2", IF(OR(Transformers!T2>=110, Transformers!T2<=75000, Transformers!T2=11, Transformers!T2=22, Transformers!T2=25, Transformers!T2=26, Transformers!T2=30, Transformers!T2=33, Transformers!T2=66),"Failed Check 3","Passed Check 3")))
```

Comment: Just saw John published the same answer I think

Comment: Thank you, I used John's sollution, much appreciated though.

Answer (score 0):

Some problems in your formula:

- before the second `OR` a comma is missing, it should be `),OR(`
- closing parenthesis of first `OR` is missing, it should be `...=66)),...`
- closing parenthesis of `IF` is missing, your formula should end to `)))`
- +1 you are looking for values between 100 and 75000, this could be done with `AND` instead of `OR`

### Another approach

To simplify your formula you can place your valid kV values in a range and refer to it; let's call it `kVolts` (one value per cell, either in one row or in one column)

The simplified formula:
`=IF(MASTER!N2="Failed Check 1","Failed Check 1",IF(META!N2="Failed Check 2","Failed Check 2"), IF(OR(AND(Transformers!T2>=110, Transformers!T2<=75000),IFERROR(MATCH(Transformers!T2,kVolts,0)>0,FALSE)) ,"Failed Check 3","Passed Check 3")))`

Comment: Thank you very much for this response; I have already applied a solution, however the syntax for using a range in future similar tasks will be very helpful.